# TSLM Error: Replacement Has Length Zero

Tags: r, time-series

I have the following data structure:

```
d <- structure(list(Date = structure(c(17349, 17350, 17351, 17352, 
                                       17353, 17354, 17355, 17356, 17357, 17358, 17359, 17360, 17361, 
                                       17362, 17363, 17364, 17365, 17366, 17367, 17368, 17369, 17370, 
                                       17371, 17372, 17373, 17374, 17375, 17376, 17377, 17378, 17379, 
                                       17380, 17381, 17382, 17383), class = "Date"), Ratio = c(67, 50, 
                                                                                               67, 50, 100, 50, 33, 67, 0, 0, 0, 0, 100, 75, 0, 0, 75, 100, 
                                                                                               67, 33, 33, 33, 50, 50, 67, 100, 67, 50, 25, 25, 33, 33, 100, 
                                                                                               33, 0)), .Names = c("Date", "Ratio"), row.names = 183:217, class = "data.frame")
```

And, using the xts package I create a time series like so:

```
library(xts)
dates = as.Date(d$Date,"%Y-%m-%d")
xs = xts(d$Ratio,dates)
```

Finally, I attempt to partition the data and train a linear model:

```
library("forecast")
train.ts <- window(xs, start = as.Date("2017-07-01"), end = as.Date("2017-08-01"))
val.ts <- window(xs, start = as.Date("2017-08-02"), end = as.Date("2017-08-04"))
d.lm <- tslm(train.ts ~ trend + I(trend^2))
```

Attempting to train the model results in the following error:

> Error in forecast:::datamat(train.ts) : replacement has length zero

What is this error and how can I resolve it?

Note: I initially suspected this error was due to NAs throughout the dataset; however, I have since coerced these to zero to no avail!

**Edit:** This is the full reproducible example (with a suggestion from @Scarabee regarding converting the xts to a ts):

```
d <- structure(list(Date = structure(c(17349, 17350, 17351, 17352, 
                                       17353, 17354, 17355, 17356, 17357, 17358, 17359, 17360, 17361, 
                                       17362, 17363, 17364, 17365, 17366, 17367, 17368, 17369, 17370, 
                                       17371, 17372, 17373, 17374, 17375, 17376, 17377, 17378, 17379, 
                                       17380, 17381, 17382, 17383), class = "Date"), Ratio = c(67, 50, 
                                                                                               67, 50, 100, 50, 33, 67, 0, 0, 0, 0, 100, 75, 0, 0, 75, 100, 
                                                                                               67, 33, 33, 33, 50, 50, 67, 100, 67, 50, 25, 25, 33, 33, 100, 
                                                                                               33, 0)), .Names = c("Date", "Ratio"), row.names = 183:217, class = "data.frame")

library(xts)
dates = as.Date(d$Date,"%Y-%m-%d")
xs = xts(d$Ratio,dates)

library("forecast")
train.ts <- window(xs, start = as.Date("2017-07-01"), end = as.Date("2017-08-01"))
val.ts <- window(xs, start = as.Date("2017-08-02"), end = as.Date("2017-08-04"))
d.lm <- tslm(as.ts(train.ts) ~ trend + I(trend^2)) # results in error Error in [.data.frame(data, , 1) : undefined columns selected
```

Output of `sessionInfo()`:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.1.0 (2014-04-10)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                           LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] forecast_7.1      timeDate_3012.100 xts_0.9-7         zoo_1.7-13       

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] colorspace_1.2-4 fracdiff_1.4-2   ggplot2_2.1.0    grid_3.1.0       gtable_0.1.2     lattice_0.20-29  munsell_0.4.2   
 [8] nnet_7.3-8       parallel_3.1.0   plyr_1.8.1       quadprog_1.5-5   Rcpp_0.11.1      scales_0.4.0     tools_3.1.0     
[15] tseries_0.10-34
```

Errors updating `xts` package:

```
require(devtools)
# results in error "Error in as.POSIXct.default(value) : do not know how to convert 'value' to class “POSIXct”"
install_version("xts", version = "0.10", repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org")

# results in error "Warning: invalid package 'https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/xts_0.10-0.tar.gz'"
install.packages("https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/xts_0.10-0.tar.gz", repos = NULL, type="source")
```

Comment: last line has `<=`  did you mean `<-`

Comment: Also, `lm` is a function name.  It is better not to assign output to object names that are similar to function names (if it is `<-` instead of `<=`)

Comment: It was late at night when I typed the question - yes I meant `<-` thanks for catching that.  The code results in the same error.  Any idea why?

Comment: @akrun I also tried renaming the `lm` variable to `d.lm` but the error persists.

Comment: `d$Date` already has Date type, so `dates = as.Date(d$Date,"%Y-%m-%d")` looks useless here.

Comment: If you convert `train.ts` from xts to ts the error disappears: `d.lm <- tslm(as.ts(train.ts) ~ trend + I(trend^2))`.

Comment: @Scarabee When I try that I get the error `Error in `[.data.frame`(data, , 1) : undefined columns selected`.  I have updated the question with the full code including your recommendation.

Comment: Strange. Could you provide your `sessionInfo()`?

Comment: @Scarabee I am using an older version of R (3.1.0).  Output of `sessionInfo()` provided above :) Thanks.

Comment: Thanks. Could you install the latest versions of xts and forecast and try again?

Comment: @Scarabee I tried updating using a couple different methods but they both fail.  Is there a special way to update this package?  Sorry for not being more familiar with this process! (Updated question with errors.)

Comment: I re-run your reproducible example without seeing any error. The result is `Call:
tslm(formula = as.ts(train.ts) ~ trend + I(trend^2))

Coefficients:
(Intercept)        trend   I(trend^2)  
   57.52770     -1.67996      0.04963   `.Do not know whether  it is what you want.

Comment: To update them you can just do `install.packages(c("xts", "forecast"))`, it should work without specifying any parameter.

Comment: @Scarabee I just installed the latest version of R and reinstalled the packages.  Now that everything is up to date, I re-ran  the script and it works as you said it would!  Thanks for everything!

Comment: @Scarabee The only issue now is that when I try to forecast using `d.lm.pred <- forecast(d.lm, h = 2, level = 0)` I get an error 
`Error in as.data.frame(newdata) : 
  argument "newdata" is missing, with no default` but that is probably a separate question!  I don't see any parameter in the docs for forecast regarding "newdata" and I can't seem to find anything relevant searching for it.

Comment: Glad it works! As for the issue with `forecast`, I can't reproduce it, it works very well on my machine...

Comment: @Scarabee Well if you'd like to post your comment as an answer I'll gladly accept it and post a new question regarding the forecast.  It looks like it's an issue with my data as when I simply use the data provided in the question it works fine.  When I use all of the data (several months worth) the error occurs.  **To recap, to fix this issue I updated my environment to the latest version of R and installed the latest versions of the xts and forecast packages and finally I changed my tslm line to `d.lm <- tslm(as.ts(train.ts) ~ trend + I(trend^2))`** Thanks, again, for all your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After updating R and packages `forecast` and `xts` to their latest versions, the error message is different:

```
d.lm <- tslm(train.ts ~ trend + I(trend^2))
# Error in names(vars)[length(vars)] <- make.names(colnames(vars[[i]])[j]) : 
#   replacement has length zero
```

We can avoid it by converting `train.ts` into a `ts` object:

```
d.lm <- tslm(ts(train.ts) ~ trend + I(trend^2))
d.lm
# Call:
# tslm(formula = ts(train.ts) ~ trend + I(trend^2))
# 
# Coefficients:
# (Intercept)        trend   I(trend^2)  
#    57.52770     -1.67996      0.04963
```

Note: it seems that `ts()` keeps the index of the times series, while `as.ts()` doesn't.